# How to bind data to a controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Below is my playlist json data.

```
{
    "id":18,
    "file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/18/01_-_MashAllah.mp3"},
    "event_id":23,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
    "name":"01 - MashAllah.mp3"
}
```

Now i want to bind id and name to a different controller am i doing something like this

playlist controller

```
.controller('playlistsController',['$scope','playlists',function($scope,playlists) {

  $scope.playlists = playlists.query();


}]);
```

view

```
<div ng-controller="playlistsController">
  <div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
    <div ng-controller='PlayerController'>

      <input type=hidden ng-model="ID" ng-value="playlist.id">
      <input type=hidden ng-model="name" ng-value="playlist.name">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
.controller('PlayerController',['$scope',function($scope) {

  console.log($scope.ID);
  console.log($scope.name);


}]);
```

but the console is showing undefined.

i don't know where i am going wrong as i am new to angular.

Comment: Where are you calling the json data from?

Comment: you have to consider controller as a class, so `playlists` object can't exist outside of controller. read a bit more about how angularjs directives should be used and what should be structure of your page in terms of ng-app, ng-controller, ng-model hierarchy.

Comment: The controller function is only a definition function... if you need to log some $scope variable, you need to use a $watch, or a function with ng-change.

Comment: @RGdent I have edited my post to avoid confusion

Comment: `$scope.playlists = playlists.query();` What are you doing with this line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the playlist data into your controller before any binding can take place. Typically this is through a service you inject, which provides the data to the controller. Once the playlist data is there, then you can bind `$scope.playlists` to it, and your ng-repeat will work.

Alternatively, just to get the binding to work, define your playlist data in the controller, and assign the list directly to $scope. This should let you see that the binding works, and then you can refactor the loading of the JSON data according to whatever best practices make sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

Swap your controller and ng-repeat, you don't want to create controller for each object in your array. Change you ng-model!

```
<div ng-controller='PlayerController'>
    <div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
        <input type=hidden ng-model="playlist.id">
        <input type=hidden ng-model="playlist.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then put your data into controller

```
.controller('PlayerController',['$scope',function($scope) {

 $scope.playlists = [{
     "id":18,
     "file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/18/01_-_MashAllah.mp3"},
     "event_id":23,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
     "updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
     "name":"01 - MashAllah.mp3"
 }]
}]);
```

Comment: I am getting playlist data from some other controller and I want to bind it to PlayerController. i have edited my code a little bit to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**IN COTROLLER YOU HAVE TO PUT THIS CODE**

```
controller('PlayerController',['$scope',function($scope) {
        $scope.playlists = [{
        "id":18,
        "file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/18/01_-_MashAllah.mp3"},
        "event_id":23,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
        "updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
        "name":"01 - MashAllah.mp3"
    },{
        "id":19,
        "file":{"url":"/uploads/playlist/file/18/01_-_MashAllah.mp3"},
        "event_id":23,"created_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
        "updated_at":"2015-11-11T10:33:52.000Z",
        "name":"01 - test.mp3"
    }];
        $scope.getvalue = function(val){
        console.log(val.id)
        console.log(val.name)
    }
}
```

**IN HTML**

```
<div ng-controller='PlayerController'>
   <div ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="playlist.id" ng-init="getvalue(playlist)">
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="playlist.name" >
   </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT**

you will get the data on the same controller when repeating the array

```
18
01 - MashAllah.mp3
19
01 - test.mp3
```

This may help you !